# data frame with pandas not outputing tabular

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, glob

I have been working on extracting data from a large number of files. I want to form a table of the data, with the file base name as the left most column and the numerical data in the next. So far, I have been testing on a folder containing 8 files, but am hoping to be able to read hundreds.

I have tried adding an index, but that seemed to cause more problems. I am attaching the closest working code I have come up with, alongside the output.

In:

```
import re, glob
import pandas as pd

pattern = re.compile('-\d+\D\d+\skcal/mol', flags=re.S)
for file in glob.glob('*rank_*.pdb'):
    with open(file) as fp:
        for result in pattern.findall(fp.read()):
            Dock_energy = {file:[],result:[]}
            df = pd.DataFrame(Dock_energy)
            df.append(df)
    df = df.append(df)
    print(df)
```

This seems to work for extracting the data, but it is not in the form I am looking for.

Out:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-10.02 kcal/mol, MII_rank_8.pdb]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-12.51 kcal/mol, MII_rank_5.pdb]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-13.47 kcal/mol, MII_rank_4.pdb]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-14.67 kcal/mol, MII_rank_2.pdb]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-13.67 kcal/mol, MII_rank_3.pdb]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-14.80 kcal/mol, MII_rank_1.pdb]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-11.45 kcal/mol, MII_rank_7.pdb]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [-12.47 kcal/mol, MII_rank_6.pdb]
Index: []
```

What is causing the fractured table, and why are my columns in reverse order from what I am hoping? Any help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: A lot depends on the format of the data in the file.  Show us what that looks like.  Reading these may help the quality of your question.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are trying to get a 2 column DataFrame with the value in one column and the file in another, I'd suggest the following. create an empty list outside of the loops.  within the inner loop, append the values as a dictionary to this list: `Dock_energy = {file:[],result:[]}` should be `myList.append({'file': file:[], 'result': result})`. After the loops, created the DataFrame with `df = pd.DataFrame(myList)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be closer to what you intend:

```
all_data = []
for file in glob.glob('*rank_*.pdb'):
    with open(file) as fp:
        file_data = []
        for result in pattern.findall(fp.read()):
            file_data.append([file, result])
    all_data.extend(file_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['file', 'result'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Yeah, it works well. I'm still new to python and really appreciate the help. What does the *.extend command cause? I clearly need to continue practicing and reading. Thanks again.

Comment: The `extend()` method adds all elements of a second list to the end of a list. It is like calling `append()` for each element of this other list. Here `all_data` grows in each loop by all elements of  `file_data`.